# Executing adb command on java program

Tags: java, android, adb, executable-jar

i made a java tool which calls certain adb command to download an app from market. When i made it into a runnable JAR, its executing fine in the system where i made it, but when  i try it on other system the adb commands just fail to execute
Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK executable jar donot work on android. Sun Java and Android are not compatible

Comment: its running in the system i built, but when m trying on some other system its not. Also if i run the java code in eclipse in the same system and then try the runnable jar it works

Comment: Maybe it has got to do with path of the adb

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the Adb executable and the related dll in your solution?
You should include it for 2 main reasons:

1. if the system hasn't the android sdk, it doen't have adb
2. the path to adb can differ from one computer to another.